# Coleman-Liau Index calculator - IndentationError: unexpected indent - why?

Tags: python, indentation

I've tried to figure out how to get my code running, but without luck. My code is supposed to calculate the Coleman-Liau index score for a text. When running the code I get "IndentationError: unexpected indent". But to me, it doesn't like look there is anything wrong with the code...I should also mention that I'm rather new to coding so I may be missing some obvious thing. Any feedback on how to solve the IndentationError will be much appreciated!
(see code below)

```py
import cs50
import math

def main():
    text = get_string("Insert text here: ")

    lettercounter = 0

    wordcounter = 0

    sentencecounter = 0

    #checks if the letters are in the alphabet.
    for i in text:

        if (i.isalpha()):

            lettercounter += 1

        # cheks for words
        elif   i == " ":

            wordcounter += 1

        elif i in [".", "!", "?"]:

            sentencecounter += 1


    L = lettercounter * 100 / wordcounter

    S = sentencecounter * 100 / sentencecounter


    # Coleman-Liau Index Score function
    ColemanLiauIndexScore = round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8)


    # printing results
        if ColemanLiauIndexScore > 16):

            print ("grade 16+")

        elif ColemanLiauIndexScore < 1):

            print ("before grade 1")

        else:

            print(f"Grade {difficulty}")

#executes main
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L = lettercounter * 100 / wordcounter

S = sentencecounter * 100 / sentencecounter


# Coleman-Liau Index Score function
ColemanLiauIndexScore = round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8)


# printing results
    if ColemanLiauIndexScore > 16):

        print ("grade 16+")

    elif ColemanLiauIndexScore < 1):

        print ("before grade 1")

    else:

        print(f"Grade {difficulty}")
```

Take note of this line > `# printing results` After which your line has an **unexpected indentation** This chunk isn't in a loop or a function so there is no reason for that indentation to be there.

```
# printing results
    if ColemanLiauIndexScore > 16):
```

Flush the `if` and `elif` to the left, and your error should be gone.

```
# printing results
if ColemanLiauIndexScore > 16):
    print ("grade 16+")

elif ColemanLiauIndexScore < 1):
    print ("before grade 1")

else:
    print(f"Grade {difficulty}")
```

Overlooked this the first time, look clearly at this line below, you are **missing a parenthesis**.

`if ColemanLiauIndexScore > 16):`

Add `(` for all your other lines.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that makes perfect sense.  I moved the if, elif and else statements to the left and it corrected the indentation error. But the indentation error has now been replaced with SyntaxError: invalid syntax, on the same line of code that the indentation error was before. Any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Hi i've edited my post to answer this question here, you are missing a '('

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and now the code is running. However, the output is always either "grade 16+" or "before grade 1" [note that the different text input should have produced different grades ranger from 1-16 and not only the extremes. Moreover, all outputs are 'grade 16+' except for the input that correctly qualifies for the outcome "before grade 1"] Since the only output produced is either "grade 16+" or "before grade 1", my guess is that something goes wrong during the calculations. Can you see where the mistake is?

Comment: I highly recommend printing the grades at each condition to see what grades you are getting, this will determine if it is a problem with your calculations or your code logic. Do take note of your unwanted spaces in your code, I see a few. In your life and your print() vs print () just to be sure

Comment: I've finally got the code to work properly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.